# Does PHP script itself count as a process?

Tags: linux, php, process, curl

My server has a limited number of concurrent processes (20) it can handle. To make sure I don't exceed I need to understand:

1. When a user is waiting for a PHP script to finish loading, does the *entire* waiting duration count as one process?
2. Most of the time waiting for the script to finish is *communicating* with a remote server via cURL... I believe most of the time is simply *waiting* for the server to respond with data. Does the whole time connected to the remote server count as a process?

I do payment processing and need to make sure nobody gets cut off. Script are run thru mod_fcgid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends.

If your server is running Apache with mod_php, then your PHP script will be run along with the Apache process and counted as one process (the one Apache is running for that HTTP request). However, if your script uses system calls for using external programs, then it naturally will spawn new processes and run them. Worth noting is that under mod_php each script is run with the user id Apache is running, so if the server has many users, each of them are using the same resources than the other.

If your web server is configured in some other way than Apache + mod_php (such as Apache + suPHP or Apache + fastCGI or Apache + mpm engine), counting the processes is a completely different beast. Then the scripts are run as the owner of the script and separating the resources is more simple. The principles are the same, though: each script is a single process unless it calls some external programs.

Comment: My server uses mod_fcgid (fastCGI). What does it mean for the server to use "system calls for using external programs"? My script contacts a database, writes to session, and connects via cURL to a remote server (the main things). I understand that these all count as processes, but does the entire PHP script itself count as a process?

Comment: System calls means using something like system() or exec() within PHP, which spawns some external system binary from `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin` or so.

Comment: So the script itself counts as a process. I do not use system calls. Do the things the script does (contacts a database, writes to session, and connects via cURL to a remote server) count as separate processes? Or will the number of processes always be 1?

Comment: Everything that's using standard PHP functions is using the same process. At least database and session is going to be a single process, with curl are you using PHP's curl functions or calling curl with some external system command?

Comment: PHP's cURL functions.

Comment: So, single process.

Comment: Thanks. In conclusion, my entire script, and everything it does, counts as one process. Therefore, the only time an issue would occur is if 21 people tried to access the PHP script at the same time (20 is the concurrent process limit).

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normally from the time you start a script until the time it ends you have at least one process running. But the script can spawn more processes or threads.

However, though I didn't look into this, I would say that if you start a script from a webserver because of a user request the script could, for example, be spawned as a thread from the webserver's process, or run as part of the webserver's process. So to give precise information one would need to know what exactly you are running.

Update: From your comment it seems it may be helpful to look into a solution where you have one process running, which then spawns threads for each request. This can improve speed a lot, but it comes at a cost (for example threads only run as long as the parent runs).

Also you might want to look into queuing the connections. In simple terms, your script can handle multiple connections and goes through each handler checking if the remote server already responded, if not it goes to the next etc. This is quite typical in handling tcp connections and you only require one process and don't need threads.

Anyways, discussion of actual programmatic solutions falls outside the scope of server administration and enters the realm of programming.

Comment: Okay, thank you. My script takes 7 seconds. My server only allows 20 concurrent processes. So if the script itself uses a process, as well as the other processes it performs, it sounds like it may not work in high traffic. If the script itself did not count as a process, that would help. Do you know if _waiting_ for a remote server to respond with data (via cURL) counts as a process?

Comment: Yes, IF the script is started as a separate process and as part of it's duty it is waiting for a remote server than that is still a process. However waiting for a remote server to answer does take almost no resources. The process is put to sleep and is woken up once the remote server answers, or the transaction times out.

Comment: See updated answer.